# redis implementation not working in setex

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am storing field in redis  `setex` to see if field is already present for an email which is being sent to the function.

Comment: I heard that people could add + signs and other useless characters to their emails while it resolves to the same email but "it's a different account".. in whatever you have the emails are user inputs?

Comment: also, when duplicate.length>0, does that mean a duplicate exists or would the check be duplicate>1?? besides that if you're checking a jobdid that's tolowercase, you should check parts in the array as such too.. `jobArr.filter(job => job.toLowerCase()==jsnMessage.jobdid)`

Comment: email are without + sign @TheBombSquad, there is some issue while storing or maybe redis is messing up.

Comment: also, when duplicate.length>0,  "Duplicate application found for given EmailID" @TheBombSquad

Comment: Your code is very suspect to a race conditions. Also, `jobArr` is very suspiciously a global..?

Comment: Also, please note that `setex` does _not_ check for duplicates in itself. (You may be looking for `setnx`.)

Comment: @AKX  how is it suspect to race conditions ?

Comment: @art Because you're not using an atomic check-and-set operation. Think about what would happen if two concurrent requests enter that function and do `.get` simultaneously, and `.set` a bit later.

Comment: @AKX SETEX IS setting jobdid which is not present for email for future, so why use setnex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249786/discussion-between-art-and-akx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for `setnx`, not `setex`. I'd put each email's jobs in a hash of their own. (This is assuming you're using a promiseful Redis library such as ioredis.)

```
async function checkForDuplicate(message) {
  const email = message.email.toLowerCase();
  const jobdid = message.jobdid.toLowerCase();
  const res = await redis.hsetnx(`jobs:${email}`, jobdid, +new Date());
  if (res === 0) {
    // duplicate jobdid
    return null;
  }
  // jobdid was added to this email's jobs hash
  return jobdid;
}

async function getJobdids(message) {
  const email = message.email.toLowerCase();
  return redis.hkeys(`jobs:${email}`); // Promise of strings
}
```

Comment: where is getJobdids being called?

Comment: @art Nowhere, it's an example of how to get the jobdids for a given message's email.

Comment: How does the post code is subject to race condition? Because Redis transactions are atomic, meaning that either every command in a transaction block is processed.

Comment: @art (a) Redis transactions don't have rollback, so some of the commands in a MULTI sequence could be executed even if some aren't. (b) You're not using MULTI.

Comment: (Redis _commands_ are atomic, but you're using multiple commands, hence: not atomic.)

Comment: hsetnx  does it offer expiry time @AKX

Comment: No, because single hash entries don't have expiry time. The whole hash can be expired with `setex`.

Comment: so how can i handle expiry time for single hash entery @AKX
Can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74611105/set-expiry-time-of-hsetnx

Comment: also i found error in current code as all jobs get expired after 1 hour irrespective  of what time they came , whereas a job which is 1 hour old should get expire to a email, can we implement it using multi ?@AKX

Comment: @art No, MULTI won't help with that. With this code, nothing gets expired by default, so I don't know where you "found error" there.

Answer (score 1):

This looks incorrect - you are only ever storing the single job-id and overwriting previous ones.

```
    if(listJobApps){
        jobArr = listJobApps.jobdids;
         let duplicate = jobArr.filter(job => job==jsnMessage.jobdid);

         if(duplicate.length > 0){
            return false;
         }
         else{
            jobArr.push(`${jsnMessage.jobdid}`);
            await onclickCache.setex(jsnMessage.email,JSON.stringify({jobdids:[`${jsnMessage.jobdid}`]}));
         }
    }
```

It should be

```
await onclickCache.setex(jsnMessage.email,JSON.stringify({jobdids:[`${jobArr}`]}));
```

Comment: added setex method in post.

Comment: also if you are using ioredis here - all these functions return promises - you don't need to re-wrap them in Promises

Comment: im using const redisJob = require('redis');