# Set Expiry time of hsetnx

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

How to Set expiry time of  hsetnx (https://redis.io/commands/hsetnx/)  to be 1 hour. Currently i don't see a param where i can set expiry time to it.

```
const IoRedis = require("ioredis");
const redis = new IoRedis();

var message = {
  "jobdid": "JCLT",
  "email": "a@k.com"
}

checkForDuplicate(message);

async function checkForDuplicate(message){

  const email    = message.email.toLowerCase();
    const jobdid = message.jobdid.toLowerCase();
    const resp   = await redis.hsetnx(`jobs:${email}`, jobdid, +new Date());

    console.log(resp);
}
```

Comment: What is your use case in the end here? Will something (else) be reading jobs from Redis and acting on them, or..?

Comment: i want to expire job related to email after 1 hour , with this code it will always block a job which is set for email @AKX

Comment: But would something else also be reading these jobs from redis, working on them, and maybe deleting/expiring them?

Comment: no only this function does this work , reading setting and expiring @AKX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to enumerate the jobs separately, then you don't really need a hash; you can just se a sequence of setnx + expire. You don't need a MULTI since setnx will only return 1 exactly once, so a second concurrent caller will never get to the expire.

```
const IoRedis = require("ioredis");
const redis = new IoRedis();

var message = {
  jobdid: "JCLT",
  email: "a@k.com",
};

checkForDuplicate(message);

async function checkForDuplicate(message) {
  const key = `jobs:${message.email.toLowerCase()}:${message.jobdid.toLowerCase()}`;
  const didSet = await redis.setnx(key, +new Date());
  if (didSet) {
    // We did set this, we're okay to set expiry too
    await redis.expire(key, 3600);
  }
  return didSet;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. You'll need to call EXPIRE on the key separately.

```js
await redis.expire(`jobs:${email}`, 3600) // expire after 3600 seconds
```

#### ADDING ATOMICITY

As requested, here is an example of using ioredis with a transaction. Not that I have not tested this code, just writing it from memory.

```js
await redis.watch(key)
redis.multi()
  .hsetnx(key, field, value);
  .expire(key, ttlInSeconds)
  .exec((err, results) => {
    /* if someone changes the key, this will error, otherwise
       you'll get an array of the results of calling each command */
  });
```

Comment: but that would break the atomicity @Guy Royse

Comment: That can be solved with a transaction. https://github.com/luin/ioredis#transaction

Comment: Can you please show in this code how to do that @Guy Royse

Comment: This should be enough for you to get it working.